# How to make two Self-referencing one to many relation Code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have the following problem, I have a "local" entity which has positive local and negative locals (yes it is strange but it is), then how can you do this on Entity Framework Coder First, Fluent Api I leave you an image to explain me better

[model diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r5yk.png)

```
 public class Local
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Local> PositiveLocals { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Local> NegativeLocals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Before fluent API (configuration), there must be an entity model (class) to be configured. Can you post your current `local` class?

Comment: this is my model, help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the two collection navigation properties, by convention EF will map your model to many-to-many relationship with implicit junction table. So to create two one-to-many relationships you need to use the following fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Local>()
    .HasMany(e => e.PositiveLocals)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("positive_local_id"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Local>()
    .HasMany(e => e.NegativeLocals)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("negative_negative_id"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Some things to note:

First, since your model have no inverse reference navigation properties, you have to use the parameterless overload of `HasOptional` / `HasRequired`.

Second, in this particular case you need to make the relationship *optional* (use `HasOptional`) because otherwise you won't be able to create `Local` record at all.

Third, you need to turn cascade delete off in order to avoid multiple cascade paths issue. It doesn't need to be turned off for both relationships as I did, but at least for the one of them. In either case you need to perform some action (deleting recursively the related `PositiveLocals` and `NegativeLocals` records) by hand before deleting a `Local` record.

Comment: just what I needed thanks :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have your entity, now all you need is a context, so it would look something like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Local> Locals { get; set; }

    public Context() : base("ConnectionStringKeyName") { }
}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
var positive = new Local
{
    Id = 1,
    Number = "One"
};

var negative = new Local
{
    Id = -1,
    Number = "Minus One"
};

negative.PositiveLocals.Add(positive);
positive.NegativeLocals.Add(negative);

using (var context = new Context())
{
    context.Locals.Add(positive);
    context.Locals.Add(negative);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What question does this answer?

Comment: @Steve Greene, your comment implies that I have not answered the OP's question. If you believe that to be the case, perhaps your should provide your own answer.

Comment: I linked to the duplicate question :)